# What is identity provider in default mvc5 template with individual accounts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've generated default Visual Studio MVC5 template with ASP.net Identity Individual Accounts. 
When I use External Authentication, identity providers are Google, Facebook etc. 
So what acts as an Identity Provider with external accounts disabled?

Comment: The database itself? (not sure I understand the question, as all the third-party log-ins do is create a token (which is then saved to that same database and re-referenced at later login)).

Comment: That makes sense. I am confused a little bit with terminology. 
Identity way means that application "outsources" its authentication process to third-party. Therefore with external providers disabled my appication "outsources" authentication to itself?

Comment: Not exactly. The -out-of-the-box identity is just an entity framework database that has [internal] authentication atop of it. The third-party logins are simply implementations of their OAuth protocols to allow users to "login with" the provider (and use them as the validator) but you still end up saving a user [profile] locally to your site. It's possible to "login with google" then go to your profile and set a password so at a future date you can either re-login with google or type your password.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the "integration point" for both ways is AuthenticationManager.SignIn method? 

It accepts ClaimsIdentity which can come from both our database and external provider and then links user with some token(cookie) that repersents that user is signed on.

Comment: Yes. The only difference is one method is a username/password (local login), and the other is using the credentials of another party (which then tells you're site "yay" or "ney"). If a successful login was forwarded, the controller creates an identity for that 3rd party and passes it off to the SignIn in lieu of a local username/password.